# how to search column value like '%test%' in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have the big text contents saved in the `co` column, I want to search if the column `co` contains particular word, something like what we do in `RDBMS` eg: where `co` like `%test%`, To achieve this should i write any filter or `Map` reduce? could somebody give an example how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
RegexStringComparator comp = new RegexStringComparator(".test.");   // or (\W|^)test(\W|$) if you want complete words only
```

or

```
SubstringComparator comp = new SubstringComparator("test");
```

and then

```
SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
    Bytes.toBytes("COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME"),
    Bytes.toBytes("co"),
    CompareOp.EQUAL,
    comp
    );
scan.setFilter(filter);
```

note that the performance for this will not be spectacular as HBase will look at each instance of the column in your table

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot It worked, one more question, I have my key which looks like :- xyz.abc.date.currenttimestamp, here date changes everyday, I want to fetch all the columns containing particular word  like you did above and between 2 dates, with the above filter is I am getting results for all the dates...

Comment: HBase also keeps a timestamp for each record (it sets it automatically to the insert time but you can also override it if you need to). You can add a timestamp range to the scan to limit the results (            scan.setTimeRange(minTimeStamp,maxTimeStamp);
)